# in this code below tr("%1") and .arg() does here?

Tags: c++, qt

I know `tr()` is used for language translation but what does `"%1"` do here?
 What's the purpose of `.arg()` in the code below?

```
 tmpItem= new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(query.value(0).toString()));
```

Comment: explanation & sample: [Qt:Using Numbered Arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-numbered-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its like a fancy `sprintf`.

You can do this kind of formatting with every `QString` (which `tr()` returns).

```
int points = 50;
int total = 100;
QString("I got %1 of %2 points.").arg( points ).arg( total );
```

Will turn to `"I got 50 of 100 points"`. Now its debatable in your code if the translation of your runtime value makes any sense at all there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `tr` is really a `QObject::tr` method that returns a `QString`, the `arg` is really `QString::arg` method. Thus, you're looking at the `QString` format system, and each `%n` is a placeholder to be replaced by the value passed to its respective `arg`. E.g.:

```
Q_ASSERT(QStringLiteral("foo%1baz").arg("bar") == QStringLiteral("foobarbaz"));
```